# When trying to edit a resx file in Visual Studio I get "The designer loader did not provide a root component but has not indicated why."

Tags: visual-studio, resx

I'm trying to edit a resx file in visual studio, but every time I try to open it I get.

"The designer loader did not provide a root component but has not indicated why."
[image]

Edit: after closing and reopening my visual studio it works again. But I have no idea what is causing this.